# Spring Boot Security cause java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/web/access/WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-starter

I like to add spring security into my web project, when I add security and extends the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` I get the following error when I start the tomcat server:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/web/access/WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613) ~[spring-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524) ~[spring-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510) ~[spring-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:570) ~[spring-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:697) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:640) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1484) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:425) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:395) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
```

This is my pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

I extended the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

I tried to add dependency as suggested in [Spring Security NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30675899/spring-security-noclassdeffounderror/30676129):

and got the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/web/csrf/LazyCsrfTokenRepository
```

I tried to add these two lines into application.properties

```
security.basic.enabled=false
management.security.enabled=false
```

Nothing works, does anyone fixed this issue?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 18):

Adding the below dependency in the pom resolved my issue:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 11):

Apart from:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

You also need:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.10.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, my old project broke because of the JWT dependency.

Comment: I love stackoverflow

Answer (score 3):

as Vinay Munagala [mentioned in Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55171414/11814208) earlier, just add this dependency to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Version could be any other `2.X.X RELEASE`.

**But**

Ensure that your `pom.xml` doesn't contain other dependencies that are "clashing" with OAuth one.

**Clashing** dependencies - the ones that are already included in the `org.springframework.security.oauth.pom`.

One of the example dependency is next:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

It is already declared in the `org.springframework.security.oauth.pom.xml`
among the other ones that OAuth functionality requires.

*Basically, if you will find Generic approach to manage your dependencies, basing on my advice - this should help you to avoid such situation in the future.*

Hope that will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete all maven dependencies from your .m2 folder and then update the maven dependencies. That resolved the issue for me. The reason is, I had two versions of spring-security-web jars in .m2 folder. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have added below dependency in my pom.xml, which resolved the issue in my case

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try excluding the auto-configuration that adds the @EnableWebSecurity to see if it fixes the problem.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
```

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12997#issuecomment-1505805005